# Questions about the subtleties of the genitive case

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

The AP style guide suggests that things like "Farmers Markets" or "Veterans Cemeteries" cannot "belong" to the members of the groups for which they were set up.

I would posit that a thing *for the use of* a group (e.g., farmers or veterans), has an implied ownership...more collectively, but I feel it's ownership nonetheless, and would write farmers' market and veterans' cemetery.

Anyone have any experience with this, and can anyone explain the subtleties of ownership vs non-ownership in these cases? I'm trying to wrap my head around why AP chose the guideline they did.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614821/2085).

Answer (score 3):

Could you post an excerpt of the guide you are referring to? That sounds very strange to me. I would use *Farmers' markets*.

Google ngrams [seems to agree with me](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=farmer%27s%20markets,%20farmers%27%20markets,%20farmers%20markets&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *farmers' market* is by far the commonest form with *farmer's markets* and *farmers markets* distant seconds.

Comment: https://www.apstylebook.com/?do=ask_editor&pg=faq  << look for the "Possessive vs. Descriptive" FAQ entry. If you subscribe to the guide, there's more detail past the login screen.