# There is a brand of ale in the United Kingdom called Farmers Ale, with no apostrophe on farmers. Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, apostrophe

There is a brand of ale called Farmers Ale. Should there be an apostrophe on farmers? Or is farmers acting as an adjective like "sports" cars?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [St. Matthew's vs. St. Matthew](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew) The famous case of Waterstones dropping the apostrophe is covered (and not for the only time). As well as  Achilles tendon (still sometimes apostrophised) / Pilton Working Mens Club / childrens clothing departments / St James Park. See also [Strunk and White says Charles's is correct ... is this still the case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62257/strunk-and-white-says-charless-is-correct-is-this-still-the-case/62261#62261).

Answer (score 4):

*The New Fowler's Modern English Usage* (Revised by R. Burchfield 1998) has the following extract in its section on apostrophes:

> **Relinquishment of the apostrophe**
>
> Since about 1900, many business firms, institutions, and journals have
> abandoned apostrophes in their titles, e.g. *Barclays Bank,  Citizens
> Advice Bureau, Diners Club, **Farmers Weekly**, Harrods, Mothers Pride
> Bread , Teachers Training College*.  (**It can be argued  that in some
> of these the word ending  in -s is a plural word used
> attributively.**)  ... This trend towards the dropping  of the
> apostrophe in such names and  titles seems certain to continue.

The bolded text above is relevant in answer to your questions.

You can find the entire text of Burchfield's book at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/TheNewFowlersModernEnglishUsageRevisedR.BurchfieldOxford1998WWBySamySalah/The%20New%20Fowler%27s%20Modern%20English%20Usage%2C%20Revised%20-%20R.%20Burchfield%20%28Oxford%2C%201998%29%20WW%20-%20By%20Samy%20Salah_djvu.txt).

Comment: In the US, Walgreens dropped its apostrophe in 1955.

Answer (score 1):

Trade names have no grammar rules. You can call a product or business whatever you want and you can punctuate or spell the name however you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The construction normally uses an apostrophe as in the following two examples.

> [Green Book Standards](https://home.army.mil/carson/application/files/9016/9755/6781/standards-book.pdf)
> *If **Soldiers’ duties** prevent them from conducting PRT during these hours, commanders will establish PRT at an alternate time during the duty day*

> [Amnesty International](https://www.amnesty.org/en/what-we-do/discrimination/womens-rights/)
> ***Women’s rights** are human rights!*

Nevertheless, your example is a trade name rather than an adjectivally qualified ale. As such it does not explicitly refer to "Farmers' ale" as an ale contextually specific to farmers. The trade product "Farmers Ale" may be drunk by anyone.

Comment: What do you do with "menswear"?

Comment: @jmucchiello I suppose that is a separate question.